# deleting sharepoint list item from listview?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007

I have get all items of a share-point list. Requirement is to delete list items form listview.  Plz guide me how it can be done ?

I have idea that it can be done by using checkbox in listview.

I am not getting how to get checked items in listview and how to delete checked items from share point list ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the SPListItemCollection.Delete method (assuming you're using the api). If not then use can use Lists.asmx to delete. For example ssomething like the code below will work

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists["List1"].Items;
SPListItem item = listItems[k];
listItems.Delete(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using SharePoint 2010 you can use client Object Model - here is howto for exactly your sceanrio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539976.aspx

Johnv2020 answer shows 2 other ways of doing it:

- if you can/need to use server side code use regular SahrePoint object model (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.delete.aspx - for SharePoint 2010 version, page also contain link to same method in previous version - Windows SharePoint Service 3/MOSS 2007).
- If you need to talk to older version of SharePoint from clinet (browser or client application) - use WebService - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824213(v=office.12).aspx